# TV13 in ubuntu 14.04 64bit error. "Not ready, Please check your connection"

Tags: 14.04, networking, remote-desktop, remote, teamviewer

everyone,

I have installed tv13 64bit (teamviewer_13.1.3026_amd64.deb) and this is my first attempt to run teamviewer in linux ever. The OS is ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

there are dependency errors (with Qt5) and I could not see the teamviewer window at all. I "fixed" that by installing Qt5 (5.10.1 to be precise), and starting teamviewer with the following line:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt5/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib/ /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer
```

you'll notice I start the executable directly from the installation directory.

The teamviewer windows pops up now, but I get this messages in the command line :

```
failed to get the current screen resources
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 173 (Unknown), sequence: 175, resource id: 87, major code: 150 (Unknown), minor code: 20
WARNING: Application calling GLX 1.3 function "glXCreatePbuffer" when GLX 1.3 is not supported!  This is an application bug!
QSGContext::initialize: stencil buffer support missing, expect rendering errors
```

Not sure if these are related to my issue though.

Also if I run the usual teamviewer script

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt5/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib/ /usr/bin/teamviewer
```

I will get the following output

```
Init...
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Starting network process (no daemon)
Network process already started (or error)
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
```

In both cases the GUI will be loaded and the edit boxes will be disabled because of the error "Not ready. Please check your connection" .

[image: teamviewer 13 in GNU Linux ubuntu 14.04]

it may be that the `teamviewerd` deamon is not running , so I tried starting that as well, but I do not see it running when I check running processes in linux with

```
ps aux | grep -i teamv
```

I only see the GUI running.

Anyone knows of any remedies ?

EDIT:

ok I just realized that the `teamviewer` executable has help menu and it is triggered only by `teamviewer help`. So I started the daemon with

```
sudo teamviewer --daemon restart
```

and I can see it running now. Yet the problem remains.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced similar issue with Ubuntu 16.04.4.. However Teamviewer started working normally once I made sure no processes were running and restarted it again. Teamviewer says that 14.04 / LTS should be supported with Qt 5.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 / Debian 8 for the moment. https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-install-TeamViewer-for-Linux/ta-p/6318

Perhaps try removing or purging Teamviewer 13 and installing from the stable repository? It could be that you have Teamviewer preview -repository enabled, which might have Ubuntu 14.04 incompatible packages.

Installing Teamviewer from the .deb-file downloadable on TV website should add the repositories for Teamviewer in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list

Currently I have:

```
        ###   TeamViewer DEB repository list

        ### NOTE: Manual changes to this file
        ###        - prevent it from being updated by TeamViewer package updates
        ###        - will be lost after using the 'teamviewer repo' command
        ###       The original file can be restored with this command:
        ###       cp /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list
        ###       which has the same effect as 'teamviewer repo default'

        ### NOTE: It is preferred to use the following commands to edit this file:
        ###       teamviewer repo                - show current repository configuration
        ###       teamviewer repo default        - restore default configuration
        ###       teamviewer repo disable        - disable the repository
        ###       teamviewer repo main [stable]  - make all TeamViewer packages available (default)
        ###       teamviewer repo tv13 [stable]  - make TeamViewer 13 packages available
        ###                             stable     omit preview and beta releases


        ### Choose stable main to receive updates for TeamViewer 13 and upcoming major releases
        ### Choose preview main to receive early updates for TeamViewer 13 and to receive major beta releases

        ### Choose stable tv13 to receive updates for TeamViewer 13
        ### Choose preview tv13 to receive early updates for TeamViewer 13

        deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
        #deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview main

        # deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable tv13
        # deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview tv13
```

Comment: I actually do have the `Teamviewer 13 preview`.  Let me check for a stable repository

Comment: hm I cannot find the stable repo for tv 13. on the website the linux version for tv13 is "preview". could you provide a link for a non preview tv13 version ?

Comment: If you've installed TV13 before, there should be sources config for it in.. /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list

Comment: I edited my answer to contain the default apt list for TV. (except my comments for getting stable)

Comment: Unfortunately even though I have the stable  source uncommented as well, The problem persists. Please see my edit though wrt to `teamviewerd`